# Double out of range when compaing within an if statement

Tags: java

The following code gives strange results when trying to save a score (It's adding on massive value as if the if statement is failing).

```
double EndScore = (double)(mScoreManager.getScore());

    if(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent() < 97.0)
    {
        EndScore += (mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()) * 100.00;
    }

    System.out.println(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()); //Output: 1.0544652507298142E-7
    System.out.println(EndScore); //Output: 1.0000105446525074

    //Increase score per dead %.
    if(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent() < 0.1)
    {
        EndScore += 20000.0;
    }
    System.out.println(EndScore); //Outout 20001.000010544652 -- WRONG HERE
    SettingsSaveLoad.setCountryScore(mCurrentWorld, (float)(EndScore));
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()` is less than 0.1, so 20000.0 is being added to `EndScore`.

Comment: What should be the value of EndScore, that, by the way, you should rename to endScore by convention?

Comment: I'm an idiot that's what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > System.out.println(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()); //Output: 1.0544652507298142E-7

means `mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()` is `1.0544652507298142 * ((10)^-7)`
which is less then `0.1`

SO After

```
EndScore += 20000.0; //1.0000105446525074+ 20000.0
```

`EndScore` becomes `20001.000010544652`

Answer (score 1):

Condition satisfying both the times.

**If value is less than  0.1 its also less than 97.0**

You put your conditions wrong i guess

`mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()` is less than 0.1.

If the first condition satisfies

```
if(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent() < 97.0)  //mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()  <97.0  true
```

its always comes in to second condition also

```
  if(mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent() < 0.1)    //mWorldCounterBox.getCurrentAlivePopulationPercent()  <0.1  true
```

side Note:

Please follow java naming conventions.Ex: **EndScore** should be **endScore**